# Dimension of the linear space of solutions to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a 6th order homogenous differential equation and I am tasked to find the dimensions of the linear space of solutions to the differential equation.

**What would be the theory that I need to know to solve this question?** Is the dimensions just the number of roots to the equation minus one repeats?

Comment: Do you mean a **linear homogeneous** ordinary differential equation? That is, $x^{(6)}+p_5(t)x^{(5)}+p_4(t)x^{(4)}+p_3(t)x'''+p_2(t)x''+p_1(t)x'+p_0(t)x=0$? Only then your question makes sense.

Comment: @user539887 oh yea, that is what they are. The only way I can find the dimensions would be to check all of the solutions form a basis right? I could guess that in this case the dimension is 6 but that is not always correct yea?

Comment: That is **always** correct (assuming of course that the coefficients are continuous): Fix $t_0\in(a,b)$; then the existence and uniqueness theorem implies that there is a linear isomorphism between the linear space of the solutions and the linear space of all possible initial values: $x(t_0)=x_0$, $x'(t_0)=x_1$, ..., $x^{(5)}(t_0)=x_5$. Since the latter has dimension $6$, the former must have dimension $6$, too. Observe that you do not need to know the form of the solutions at all.

Comment: @user539887 , thanks mate. Remember reading something like that in the textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a linear differential equation you have as many dimensions as you have independent solutions to the (homogeneous) equation.  The is often the degree of the equation, so six here.  It works if the equation is linear in the dependent variable and its derivatives.  The idea is that you can multiply any solution by a constant to get a new solution or add any two solutions to get a new solution.  That is the defining property of a vector space.  As you can multiply by any constant, you can multiply by zero to get a solution that is constantly zero.  That is the identity element of the space.

Comment: I do not think that the OP has **nonhomogeneous** linear ODE in mind. On the contrary, their mention of "the linear space of solutions to the differential equation" pretty clearly shows that they mean a **homogeneous** linear ordinary differential equation.

Comment: @user539887:  I agree.  I have updated it.